# Transaction deadlock starvation

Tags: .net, sql-server

Need your help with some database related issue. Struggling to resolve a deadlock issue which is causing a starvation. I have transaction 1 for example and transaction 2. T1 and T2 deadlocks and then T1 gets chosen as the victim. T2 then completes and T1 retries but in that time T3 is created and causes a deadlock with T1 again and T1 gets chosen as the victim again. This continues with T4 T5 and so on. Now i know timestamping a Transaction will resolve the issue but do not know how this is implemented. Do i have to do it manually in code or is it just a matter of a configuration in SQL Server? Please help.

Comment: What is your goal here? To stop "T1" from deadlocking? If so, increase it's priority (which will cause "T2" to fail).

Comment: Your best bet is to diagnose and solve the actual deadlock. Increasing the priority of T1 is possible, but it will instead cause any other transaction to fail, and if T1 is consistently chosen as a victim (and retried) that usually means you can afford to not execute T1, but not all the rest. You cannot both have deadlocks, and also ensure every statement always executes -- solve the deadlocks instead.

Comment: As the first step in avoiding deadlocks, I suggest query and index tuning to ensure only the data actually needed is touched.

Comment: Im trying to stop T1 from being chosen has the deadlock victim everytime by using timestamping. So what im trying to do is if T1 is a younger transaction than T2 then T1 should be chosen has the victim but then when T1 retries and T3 has come along and causes a deadlock again, T3 should be chosen as the victim because it is the younger transaction

Comment: SQL Server chooses which process to pick as the victim primarily on what transaction is least expensive to roll back (so `SELECT` will be picked before any modification statement, for example). The only knob you have for overriding it is `SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY`. It's not possible to get SQL Server to do what you suggest and pick the last started transaction -- not automatically and not manually either, since you can't detect deadlocks like the engine can.